# Killall -9 chrome, but not chrome-beta

Tags: linux, bash-scripting, kill

Both Google Chrome and Google Chrome Beta are named "chrome" in the process list.

I want to kill all instances of chrome, but keep all instances of chrome beta;)

Any pointers as to what could be the best way from a bash script?;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `pkill -f` instead of killall. The `-f` switch is necessary to use any part of the full process name to match. You can use `pgrep -fa` first to list the processes in full and test your search string.